# Kids TV show on Animax with a red bird

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, anime

I am looking for a name of a kids TV show. I used to watch it on Animax about 6-10 years ago (I am not sure). It was about this bird which used to draw himself with this big pencil on the beginning. I dont remember if it was Chinese-Japanese or Korean, so it´s really hard to find. I tried to draw the picture how I remember this bird looked like. I know he was red with yellow or brown and had this big beak. And from what I have already found, the red bird from Peep and the Big Wide World look very similar.  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be Kyoro chan!

- [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyorochan)
- [Opening credits on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0-7HZb-WyI)

[image]